# Как центрировать текст относительно картинки

Tags: html, css

Хочу сделать примерно как на примере в [Дриббле](https://dribbble.com/shots/2314157-Daily-UI-Day-1/attachments/439137)

Пока застрял на моменте, как центрировать текст относительно изображения (секция авторизации) и, также, предполагаю, что автор на Дриббле реализовал секцию с авторизацией совсем по-иному и намного лучше меня.

Подскажите, пожалуйста как он это сделал или как мне сделать лучше (чувствую, что иду не в том направлении).

[Ссылка на Codepen](https://codepen.io/nickleekers/pen/aaqqoj)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>exp.1</title>
</head>
<div class="autor"><h3>lorem imsum doler</h3></div>
<div class="title"><h1>become a member<h1></div>
<div class="description"><h2>desription about this amazing website and his servises</h2></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="auth_facebook">
 <script type="text/javascript" async src="#"></script>
 <img src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20171216/213/facebook-logo-png-5a35528eaa4f08.7998622015134439826976.jpg">
 <h4><a href="#">sign up for facebook</a></h4>
 </div>

 <div class="auth google">
 <script type="text/javascript" async src="#"></srcipt>
 <img src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180319/sue/kisspng-social-media-google-social-network-google-logo-google-plus-logo-5ab02ccc75f733.8818363015214952444832.jpg">
 <h4>sign up for google</h4>
 </div>

 <div class="auth twitter">
 <script type="text/javascript" async src="#"></srcipt>
 <img="http://pngimg.com/uploads/twitter/twitter_PNG28.png">
 <h4>sign up for twitter</h4>
 </div>
</div>
</hr>
<div class="auth email">
<h4>u can aslo sign up in using an emailadres</h4>
<a href="#">use your email &rarr;</a>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Для начала, скорее всего на вашем примере, закреплённом в начале используется система grid. Вы хотите в точности как там дизайн? Есть несколько вариантов построения такого шаблона  : 1 - Grid, 2- flex ну и костыльные методы

Comment: Нет, не в точности, цитирую: "Когда вы определились с дизайном, идите и попробуйте сверстать его на CodePen...Не стоит расстраиваться если ваша копия будет отличатся от оригинала. Продолжайте практиковаться с разными дизайнами и со временем вы заметите существенные улучшения."

Comment: дайте мне пару минут, сейчас я укажу вам на ваши ошибки.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YOeMXa - держи, мне скучно стало, решил по гридам пройтись и вспомнить) Тренируйся

Answer (score 1):

Здесь я может быть ошибся где то

Это мой первый ответ на SO

**Смотреть на полном экране**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p,
span,
a {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: 680px;
  transform: translateY(30px);
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.child1 img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.child2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.child2-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.child2 h2 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.child2-wrapper p {
  color: #666;
}

.child2-wrapper p:nth-of-type(1) {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.child2-wrapper p:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.fa-google-plus {
  color: tomato;
}

.fa-facebook {
  color: darkblue;
}

.fa-twitter {
  color: lightblue;
}

.fa {
  padding: 0 10px;
  float: left;
  transform: translateY(5px);
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.footer-link {
  color: lightgreen;
}

.footer-link .fa {
  float: none;
}

.button span {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child1">
      <img src="https://odysseyonline-img.rbl.ms/simage/https%3A%2F%2Faz616578.vo.msecnd.net%2Ffiles%2F2017%2F01%2F05%2F636192057862681874-625434473_Black-White-New-York-City-Wallpaper-.jpg/2000%2C2000/dMJuG2aNGXJqK2Vu/img.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
      <div class="child2-elem">
        <div class="child2-wrapper">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor.
          </p>
          <h2>Become a member</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum sapiente natus iste, autem ipsam, et ratione. Amet molestias nam qui reprehenderit doloribus.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="child2-elem">
        <a href="" class="button">
          <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i><span>sign up using google</span>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="button">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span>sign up using facebook</span>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="button">
          <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i><span>sign up using twitter</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="child2-elem footer">
        <span>You also sign in using an emailadres</span>
        <a href="" class="footer-link">use your email <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с того что у вас закрывающие теги `</script>` написаны с ошибками. Внимательнее проверяйте синтаксис.
 1. - Помещайте скрипты в конец `<body>` прямо перед его закрывающим тэгом.
 2. ```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="autor"><h3>lorem imsum doler</h3></div>
    <div class="title"><h1>become a member<h1></div>
    <div class="description"><h2>desription about this amazing website and his servises</h2></div>
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="auth_facebook">
                  <img src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20171216/213/facebook-logo-png-5a35528eaa4f08.7998622015134439826976.jpg">
                  <h4><a href="#">sign up for facebook</a></h4>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="auth_google">
                    <img src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180319/sue/kisspng-social-media-google-social-network-google-logo-google-plus-logo-5ab02ccc75f733.8818363015214952444832.jpg">
                    <h4>sign up for google</h4>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="auth_twitter">
          <img src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20171216/213/facebook-logo-png-5a35528eaa4f08.7998622015134439826976.jpg">
                        <h4>sign up for twitter</h4>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </hr>
<div class="auth_email">
<h4>u can aslo sign up in using an emailadres</h4>
<a href="#">use your email &rarr;</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" async src="#"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="#"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```

```
body{
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
container{
  display: border-box;
}
ul div{
  width: 1vw;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
ul li{
  display: inline;
}

    img{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
```

Я так понял вы хотели что-то подобное?

Comment: Ну, я примерно так и пытался сделать, спасибо, пойду почитаю о grid и flex чтобы посмотреть как можно сделать это лучше и более похоже на шаблон с Дриббле

Comment: @NickLeeker Успехов вам, я привел не самый лучший пример построения, но я думаю вы поняли смысл. И будте внимательнее к правописанию тэгов!

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич, не всегда `<script>` должен быть в конце страницы, не вводите людей в заблуждение.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 я посоветовал это человеку, который только начал учить html - я согласен, не всегда, но для начала пусть они будут в одном месте на странице.

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич, раз он начинает изучать HTML, то пусть знает как происходит отрисовка страницы, тогда он сам поймёт куда пихать определённый скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё так реализовать. Без `flex` и `grid`.

```css
.login {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 20px); /* во всю ширину - ширина внутренних отступов */
  padding: 10px; /* Внутренние отступы */
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 10px; /* Отступ вниз */
  text-decoration: none !important; /* Убираем нижнее подчёркивание (всегда) */
  background: #ddd;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.login img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.login span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px); /* учитывая картинку и её отступ */
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden; /* Прячем, чтобы не вылезло и не поломало дизайн */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Текст в строку */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* Если не влезает, добавляем "..." в конце */
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="login">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/36x36">
  <span>VK</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="login">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/36x36">
  <span>Facebook</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="login">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/36x36">
  <span>Google</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="login">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/36x36">
  <span>А тут будет много букв, очень много, прям ваще очень много, на столько, что аж не влезает.</span>
</a>
```